# Seaborn line plot: don't aggregate and plot all observations

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

My raw data look like:

```
>df
   Jan   Feb    ...  Dec
0   2     4           4
1   5     3           3
```

where each row is monthly production of a solar panel. **I wanted to plot each row**, so I can visually check if some panel were having unexpected behavior. So I convert to long and plot it using seaborn:

```
df = pd.melt(df)
ax = sns.lineplot(x = variable, y = value, data  = df)
```

However this just give mean for each month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can just do:

```
df.T.plot()
```

and output:

[image]

If you insist on seaborn, you need to pass `hue`, something like

```
sns.lineplot(data=df.stack().reset_index(name='val'),
             x='level_1',
             y='val',
             hue='level_0')
```

where `level_0` and `level_1` come from .`reset_index` of unnamed sources index.

You need to do more for correct ordering of `x-axis`.